# Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python, windows, pandas

I'm running a python script in a remote computer in a Venv. It worked just fine this friday but for some reason now it returns this error:

```
File "D:\PATH\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I check my versions and are up to date (numpy-1.16.2 and pandas-0.24.2) and I can only install dependencies from "pip". I tried to uninstall and then install pandas, numpy in several orders to no avail. I cannot use anaconda or similar and can't use ubuntu's shell either. Does anybody know how to fix this and how to prevent it from happening again? It made us lose a few working hours.

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur when multiple versions of numpy are installed. Check to make sure you only have one version of numpy installed.

You can also just repeatedly call
`pip uninstall numpy` 
until all versions are uninstalled and then use
`pip install numpy` 
to get only the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

you don't have numpy in Venv (which pandas requires), you are probably calling something in pandas that suddenly requires numpy, try sourcing the virtualenv and running pip install numpy

Not sure about windows but in unix I would:

```
source D:\PATH\Venv\bin\activate
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Didn't work. The Venv recognizes and has numpy installed

Comment: try source D:\PATH\Venv\bin\activate 
AND THEN pip freeze    see what you get